# Can an inherited static function access an overridden static private data member?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am wondering about the following:

In static.h:

```
class Base
{
    private: static const char* className;

    public:  static const char* getClass() { return className; };

};


class Sub : public Base
{
    private: const static char* className;
};
```

And in static.cpp:

```
#include "static.h"
#include <iostream>

const char* Base::className = "Base";
const char* Sub ::className = "Sub";

int main() {    std::cout << Sub::getClass(); }

// outputs "Base"
```

Is it possible to inherit such a function and have it use an overridden data member?

Comment: Member variables are not polymorphic in C++...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth So never :)

Comment: Why would you need this? You can access `Base::className` and `Sub::className` just fine?!

Comment: Oh no! ::getClass() in C++! Java is comming!

Comment: @KerrekSB it's called a theoretical question. The code above is written for the occasion. Actually they are private, so you can't, but to answer you question really, I'm working on a better OOP model for javascript and I was wondering if it would be really lacking if I didn't support this behaviour, which I consider it's not if it's not even possible in C++. However the method could be more complex than a getter of a const and it would be handy if you didn't have to copy/paste methods just because some piece of data changes in you subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but this is not 'overriding', it is actually 'hiding'. The class can access its own private members, and its data members hide declarations using the same name in base classes.